# TableView reload data is not working when it is called from other class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have two class , `class A` with container and `UISegmentControl` in `class B` I have a `UITableView` which is embedded with the container.
Initially when loading data the `UITableView` is loading properly when I choose different button in the `UISegmentControl` I did reloading in `class B` for which table reloading is not happening!

**Class A with Container**

```
@implementation UpgradeVCViewController
int flag = nil;

- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];
 _containerView.alpha = 1.0;
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
HHSlideView * slideView = [[HHSlideView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height -64) ];
slideView.delegate = self;

[_iconView addSubview:slideView];
[self.view addSubview:_containerView];

-(NSInteger)numberOfSlideItemsInSlideView:(HHSlideView *)slideView
{
   return 3;
}

-(NSArray *)namesOfSlideItemsInSlideView:(HHSlideView *)slideView
{
   NSArray *items = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"PREMIUM ECONOMY",@"BUSINESS",@"FIRST", nil];
return items;
```

}

```
- (void)slideView:(HHSlideView *)slideView didSelectItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index {
NSLog(@" index %li", index);

flag = index  ;

if(flag == 1 || flag == 2)
{
    SampleTableViewController * obj = [[SampleTableViewController alloc]init];

   [obj.reloadtable reloadData];

   }
 }
```

**Class B**

```
-(void)sampleMethod
    {

 [self.reloadtable reloadData];

  }
```

Comment: put your code which you have tried

Comment: Are you use call back method?

Comment: You need some mechanism to send action from control in Class B to Class A where you have your table view. You can use Notification, delegate or even blocks. I would suggest using delegate. Make class A as the delegate of B and than delegate action from class B to class A where you can reload the table data.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to use NSNotificationCentre for reload tablview in containerView(class B).

Add

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(reloadTablViewWithNotification:) name:@"reloadTableView" object:nil];

-(void)reloadTablViewWithNotification:(NSNotification *)notification{
    NSLog(@"%@",[notification object]); // prints "Your object"
// here you can reload your tableview
}
```

// post when your need

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"reloadTableView" object:@"Your object"];
```

Comment: @gowtham did you try this answer ?

Comment: in which class you add this notificationCentre ?

Comment: i added the Notification center in class A (which has the container view) and posted it in class B (tableviewcontroller)

Comment: in which class you need to reload tableview ?

Comment: in class B(tableviewcontroller)

Comment: so you need to add Notification and its method in Class B and post through class A .

Comment: ya you were corct! thnks